# MVC4 Redirect After File Download

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, filestreamresult

I have an ActionResult method in my controller that returns a FileStreamResult for a download file scenario.  After the file is downloaded, I would like to redirect the user to a different view.  How can I best accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it. You can only return one response from your action and that will contain the file. You cannot also put a redirection header in it, best you can do is redirect first, then start the download.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried your suggestion to redirect first then start the download but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There's no real easy way to do that, as file downloading is a client/browser thing.

There is a JavaScript technique mentioned [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/GruffCode/archive/2010/10/28/detecting-the-file-download-dialog-in-the-browser.aspx).

**TLDR**: Create a cookie on the client, override it in the file download (e.g delete it by setting a cookie with a past expiry), keep checking every so often on the client if the cookie is gone, when it is, do a redirect.

Comment: I'll give it a try but I think this approach will make it more difficult to maintain and support.

Comment: @MikeC - agreed. I don't recommend this approach at all. I agree with Ufuk. But this is a last resort.